# Play mp3 file in C

Tags: c, mp3, libcurl, audio-player

I want to play mp3 files on the internet without downloading them. So, I use libcurl to get it as a stream in memory, like this:

```
static size_t use_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
     /* stream is NULL */
     /* What to do with the stream of data ? */
}

CURLcode download_file(const char *url, const char *path, curl_progress_callback progress) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    if ((curl = curl_easy_init())) {
        if (progress) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress);
        }
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, use_data);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return res;
}
```

How can I parse the stream in memory to play sounds ?

Comment: There are many possible answers to your question.

Comment: @iharob: Well, as it seems, I get no answers.

Comment: Yes because you must ask a specific question. And your question is very ambiguos. Have you searched about libraries that can help playing mp3?

Comment: @iharob: Yes, a lot. But what I want is more specific than reading from a file. Reading directly from memory, line by line.

Comment: I think `ffmpeg`'s `libavcodec` can read from memory buffers, I just don't remember exactly how, search for it's documentation.

Comment: @iharob: Thanks for your note, but I actually intend my app to be cross-platform.

Comment: @AFAIK `ffmpeg` is cross platform.

Comment: @iharob: Oh, yes it seems to be. I think I just didn't do enough research. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way for you IMHO would be using lightweight MP3 decoding library. For example, minimp3 does it's job and consists of only 2 files.

http://keyj.emphy.de/minimp3

The API is very simple and a usage example can be found here: https://github.com/corporateshark/PortAMP/tree/master/src/Decoders/MP3